# S3 what is recommended hierarchy for storing objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been playing around with Amazon S3 and I wonder why would I need to use multiple buckets. I just though I would name my objects according to hierarchy they belong to, eg. `blog/articles/2016/08/article-title.jpg` and store them all in one bucket. The folders will be created in this case. Or is there any reason why would I need multiple buckets to store uploaded files?

And if so, what is the proper design of having multiple buckets? Let's say I need to categorise files by type year and month. I suppose I can't have buckets in a bucket.

Comment: Note that there is no need to create folders in a bucket, unless you are uploading files manually in the console into folders that aren't selectable.  Creating an object *named* `blog/articles/2016/08/article-title.jpg` using the API/SDK will cause all of those intermediate folders to appear. S3 doesn't actually have any folders, it just displays them in the console based on the `/` delimiters in the object keys (names).  Because of this, there are no performance considerations based on how many objects are "in" a folder.

Answer (score 4):

AWS guidance in [S3 Bucket Restrictions and Limitations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html) states:

> There is no limit to the number of objects that can be stored in a
>   bucket and no difference in performance whether you use many buckets
>   or just a few. You can store all of your objects in a single bucket,
>   or you can organize them across several buckets.

I would keep it simple, and store that type of asset data in a single bucket, perhaps divided up into a few 'top level' key name prefixes (folders) such as `images`, `scripts`, etc.